# Cant create a nested resource in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to create a button that makes a given user an admin. For that I'd like to create a route for the request `post /users/:id/admin`. In order to do that, I'm trying to create a nested resource like so:

```
resources "/users", UserController, only: [:new, :create, :index] do
  resources "/admin", UserController, only: [:post]
end
```

But when I run `mix phx.routes | grep users`, I only get those routes:

```
user_path  GET     /users            StorexWeb.UserController :index
user_path  GET     /users/new        StorexWeb.UserController :new
user_path  POST    /users            StorexWeb.UserController :create
```

As if the nested resource was not declared. What is wrong with my resource declaration ? and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is in `only: [:post]`. There is no such action `:post`, so you end-up with nothing. You probably wanted this:

```
resources "/users", UserController, only: [:new, :create, :index] do
  resources "/admin", UserController, only: [:create]
end
```

I will open up an issue in Phoenix to raise in those cases to avoid further confusion.

Answer (score 0):

With nested resources, that would be not a `resource`, but a `scope`. The following should work:

```
scope "/users" do
  resources "/", UserController, only: [:new, :create, :index]

  resources "/admin", UserController, only: [:post]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario I prefer using `post`/`get` directly instead of using `resources` because I am not forced to use a specific function name such as `create` especially if the controller of your nested resource has only one endpoint/function (e.g. `/users/admin` with `post`).

```
resources "/users", UserController, only: [:new, :create, :index] do
  post "/admin", UserController, :post
end
```